# Proof that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^j}{j!} \cdot e^{-\theta} \cdot j$ reduces to $\theta$

Tags: solution-verification, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Consider the following sum:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^j}{j!} \cdot e^{-\theta} \cdot j$$

This should reduce to $\theta$.

My approach:

$$= e^{-\theta} \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^j}{j!} \cdot j$$
$$= e^{-\theta} \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^j}{(j-1)!}$$
$$= e^{-\theta} \cdot \theta \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^{(j-1)}}{(j-1)!}$$
$$= e^{-\theta} \cdot \theta \cdot e^{\theta}$$
$$= \theta$$

I think there is a shortcut involved, i.e. in the second last step I am "cheating" a bit. Would I not need $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^{j}}{j!}$ in order to plug in $e^{\theta}$ for the taylor series?

Comment: No Vito, you are not cheating. $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\theta^{j}/j! =e^{\theta}-1$ and not $e^{\theta}$. And thus, $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\theta^{j}/j!$ is equal to $e^{\theta}$.

Comment: Great, thanks Gandalf!